# Codeigniter Functions Parameter Issue

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have been working on codeigniter for past 1 year, but never found this problem, probally because i have been always working with functions with parameters

let me show u the issue

say i have a function like this in my front

```
class user extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        @session_start();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
    }
    /*------------for registration-------------*/
    function register()
    {
       }
```

now it will be called like this

```
http://example.com/user/register
```

i am passing no arguments in the register function

now if i write like this in the address bar

http://example.com/user/register/abc/abd

then also the register function will be called showing no error

as i am passing two parameters for the register function, and on register function i am not catching them..

i want in such case the `404 error` should be shown,, how can i do this...

Comment: Its not an issue with Codeigniter. That's how it is made. By the way most website work like that. I don't know why you want to show 404 instead of just ignoring those parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [URI class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) to check if the third URI segment contains anything and if it does you can use [`show_404()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html):

```
if($this->uri->segment(3) !== FALSE)
{
  show_404();
}
```

Comment: absolutely simple and effective, realy loved it like a charm... but cud i use routing techniques for this??

Comment: @Saswat - I don't see anything in the URI routing section that could help you with this. It may be possible, but I don't know how.